# Error: Unable to resolve module 'XXXXX' could not be found within the project

Tags: android, react-native

I'm keep getting this error whenever I try to install any npm package on my windows 10 for android. It shows the package added in android studio and node_modules as well. However when i import the npm package in JS file and run the project the error comes up. With the below instructions :

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong? I'm using react-native 0.63.2

Answer (score 0):

It means the metro bundler does not know there is a new package installed. In that case, turn off the metro bundler and follow the steps you listed above and then npx react-native run-android. Those steps clear the cache and help metro find the new package that was installed.

Comment: Okay, delete the app off of device. In Android studio go to File --> invalidate caches and restart. Build in android studio to see if you encounter more errors, if not, try the npx react-native run-android command again.

Comment: Yes I tried those steps many times, I think node_modules for the npm libraries are not getting installed on my system properly.

Comment: @Maverick did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Check in any of the files you were working on recently and be sure you are not mistakenly importing `XXXXX` somewhere, in my case it was `process` as shown in the image above. Most times it happens when you invoke a function or method within your module